# "Let's talk math/geography..." meaning

Tags: sentence-construction, spoken-english, conversation

I was reading this article (linked below the sentence) when I came across this:

> First, let’s talk geography.
>
> -- *[Smithsonian Magazine](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/whats-difference-between-england-britain-and-uk-180959558/)*

I could get what it means but the grammar behind it is still a mystery to me. I also searched a bit and found similar results with words like "math/history"....etc

So is  "geography" an adverb here or actually it's  an indirect object but the preposition "about" is just omitted and if so , why is it omitted? Is this grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is written in a **conversational style**, even though it is in a respected publication like *Smithsonian Magazine.*

You can tell this because of the *contraction* "let's".  Many people were taught in school that contractions should be used in speaking (and dialog) but not in formal writing.

The word "geography" is functioning as the **object** of the verb talk.

It would be more formal (or "more correct") to say:

> - Let's talk **about** geography.
> - Let's talk **about** television.
> - Let's talk **about** you.

If you put in a different noun (*television*) or pronoun (*you*), you'll notice that these "about" phrases are also acting as the object of "*talk*".

None of them is an adverb.

It is an acceptable **idiom** in conversational English to drop the word "about" in some of these sentences:

> **Yes:** Let's talk geography.
>
> **Yes:** Let's talk television.
>
> *Awkward:* Let's talk you.

The last one is very awkward, and *very informal*.  It's pronounced the same way as "let's talk about YOU":  "let's talk YOU", *not* "let's TALK you", *and not* "let's talk, you."

You can write it in quotes to make this more clear:

> *Still awkward:*  Let's talk "you".
>
> *Still awkward:*  Let's talk "you" for a moment.

***You can always leave the word 'about' in the sentence and be correct.***

Comment: Thanks soo much for the answer. But is omitting "about" popular amony all English speakers or at least the majority of them or is it just specific to some dialects or countries? Bec for some unknown reason, my heart tells me that it may be only specific to Americans, lol.

Comment: I can only answer for American English.  It’s done here, but it sounds a little strange, like someone is trying hard to sound sophisticated.

Comment: So in American English it's almost used by teachers and maybe speechers also.